# Multiple controllers on Spring Tools Suite

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, crud

I have made my first CRUD app on Spring MVC following a sample of sivalabs. The problem is when I add another controller class the application does not start. 
If I remove the annotation @Controller the app works. Thanks in advance.

### HTTP Status 404 - /SpringMVCHibernate/

type Status report
message /SpringMVCHibernate/

### description The requested resource is not available.

VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.9.6.RELEASE/7.0.53.B.RELEASE

Comment: Please post your Class code to which you are making controller.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing..  
- Check if there is any conflict in the url pattern.  <strike>Make sure your 'RequestMapping's are unique.</strike>   ["[When a URL matches multiple patterns, a sort is used to find the most specific match.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-pattern-comparison)"] 
- Also, check if you are trying to visit the correct url [when you start the server, it many not take you to valid URLs.]. Check the logs in the console to find out which all url mappings have been identified by the spring.

Please post the code to check further.